# page reload in asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I made a master page and added a button to it and some js code to the button, but when i clicked the button it reloads the page due to which the js file stop working.
The button code is :

```
<button id="database" onclick="myFunction()" style="background-color:transparent; color: #FFFFFF; border:none;"">
            <img class="image" id="database_" src="images/database.png" style="width: 81px" /><br />
            DataBase</button>
```

The Js code is :

```
function myFunction() {
$("#database_").removeClass("image");
```

}

image code is :

```
.image{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

}

so can anyone help to stop page refresh and js code running

Comment: Is the button inside a `<form>`?

Comment: yes its inside the <form>

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the button type, like this:

```
<button type="button" id="database" onclick="myFunction()" style="background-color:transparent; color: #FFFFFF; border:none;"">
            <img class="image" id="database_" src="images/database.png" style="width: 81px" /><br />
            DataBase</button>
```

The default, is submit, that submits the form when you click.